# Creating a two-color object with tinter for bat and ball game

Tags: python, object, tkinter

This is my very first code ever and I know nothing about it, but I have created a bat and Ball game and inspired by this 9gagger https://9gag.com/gag/aYgb2mN I wanted to create something similar. How can I double-color my bat object into looking like a cigaret?

As I said, this is my very first code and most I found out by trying it out, so any improvements on my code is welcome!

```
import tkinter as TK
import time

VERT,HOREZ=0,1
xTOP,yTOP = 0,1
xBTM,yBTM = 2,3
MAX_WIDTH,MAX_HEIGHT = 640,480
xSTART,ySTART = 50,200
BALL_SIZE=10
RUNNING=True

def close():
  global RUNNING
  RUNNING=False
  root.destroy()

def move_right(event):
  if canv.coords(paddle)[xBTM]<(MAX_WIDTH-7):
  canv.move(paddle, 20, 0)

def move_left(event):
  if canv.coords(paddle)[xTOP]>7:
    canv.move(paddle, -20, 0)

def determineDir(ball,obj):
  global delta_x,delta_y
  if (ball[xTOP] == obj[xBTM]) or (ball[xBTM] == obj[xTOP]):
    delta_x = -delta_x            
  elif (ball[yTOP] == obj[yBTM]) or (ball[yBTM] == obj[yTOP]):
    delta_y = -delta_y

root = TK.Tk()
root.title("Bouncing Ball")
root.geometry('%sx%s+%s+%s' %(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT, 100, 100))
root.bind('<Right>', move_right)
root.bind('<Left>', move_left)
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', close)

canv = TK.Canvas(root, highlightthickness=0)
canv.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

top = canv.create_line(0, 0, MAX_WIDTH, 0, fill='blue',
                     tags=('top'))
left = canv.create_line(0, 0, 0, MAX_HEIGHT, fill='blue',
                      tags=('left'))
right = canv.create_line(MAX_WIDTH, 0, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT,
                  fill='blue', tags=('right'))
bottom = canv.create_line(0, MAX_HEIGHT, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT,
                  fill='blue', tags=('bottom'))

ball = canv.create_rectangle(0, 0, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE,
                  outline='black', fill='black', tags=('ball'))
paddle = canv.create_rectangle(100, MAX_HEIGHT - 20, 170, 470,
                  outline='black', fill='white', tags=('rect'))


#row is 64 boxes wide
brick=list()

#trachea
for i in range(32,34):
  for row in range(0,5):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#first line of lungs and trachea
for i in range(26,31):
  for row in range(5,6):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(32,34):
  for row in range(5,6):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))
for i in range(35,40):
  for row in range(5,6):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#second line of lungs and trachea
for i in range(24,31):
  for row in range(6,7):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(32,34):
  for row in range(6,7):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))
for i in range(35,42):
  for row in range(6,7):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#third line of lungs and trachea
for i in range(23,31):
  for row in range(7,8):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(32,34):
  for row in range(7,8):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))
for i in range(35,43):
  for row in range(7,8):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#fourth line of lungs and trachea
for i in range(22,31):
  for row in range(8,9):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(32,34):
  for row in range(8,9):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))
for i in range(35,44):
  for row in range(8,9):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#fifth line of lungs and bifurcation of trachea
for i in range(21,45):
  for row in range(9,10):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#sixth line of lungs and bifurcation of trachea
for i in range(20,46):
  for row in range(10,11):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#seventh-ninth lines of lungs
for i in range(19,31):
  for row in range(11,14):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(35,47):
  for row in range(11,14):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#tenth-fourteenth lines of lungs
for i in range(18,31):
  for row in range(14,19):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(35,48):
  for row in range(14,19):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#fiftenth-eighteenth lines of lungs
for i in range(17,31):
  for row in range(19,23):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(36,49):
  for row in range(19,23):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#ninteenth line of lungs
for i in range(17,30):
  for row in range(23,24):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(37,49):
  for row in range(23,24):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#twentieth line of lungs
for i in range(17,29):
  for row in range(24,25):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(38,49):
  for row in range(24,25):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#twenty-first line of lungs
for i in range(17,28):
  for row in range(25,26):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(39,48):
  for row in range(25,26):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#twenty-second line of lungs
for i in range(17,27):
  for row in range(26,27):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(40,48):
  for row in range(26,27):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#twenty-third line of lungs
for i in range(18,26):
  for row in range(27,28):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(41,48):
  for row in range(27,28):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#twenty-fourth line of lungs
for i in range(19,25):
  for row in range(28,29):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(42,47):
  for row in range(28,29):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#twenty-fifth line of lungs
for i in range(19,24):
  for row in range(29,30):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(43,47):
  for row in range(29,30):
    brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

delta_x = delta_y = 1
xold,yold = xSTART,ySTART
canv.move(ball, xold, yold)

while RUNNING:
  objects = canv.find_overlapping(canv.coords(ball)[0],
                                canv.coords(ball)[1],
                                canv.coords(ball)[2],
                                canv.coords(ball)[3])

  #Only change the direction once (so will bounce off 1st
  # block even if 2 are hit)
  dir_changed=False
  for obj in objects:
    if (obj != ball):
      if dir_changed==False:
        determineDir(canv.coords(ball),canv.coords(obj))
        dir_changed=True
      if (obj >= brick[0]) and (obj <= brick[len(brick)-1]):
        canv.delete(obj)
      if (obj == bottom):
        text = canv.create_text(330,400,text="OOPS! TRY AGAIN!")
        canv.coords(ball, (xSTART,ySTART,
                         xSTART+BALL_SIZE,ySTART+BALL_SIZE))
        delta_x = delta_y = 1
        canv.update()
        time.sleep(3)
        canv.delete(text)
  new_x, new_y = delta_x, delta_y
  canv.move(ball, new_x, new_y)

  canv.update()
  time.sleep(0.005)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for instead of repeating the same code over and over.

```
for start, stop, row_start, row_stop in ((32, 34, 0, 5),
                                         (26, 31, 5, 6),
                                         (32, 34, 5, 6)):  ## etc
    for ctr in range(start, stop):
        for row in range(row_start, row_stop):
            brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(ctr*10, row*10,
                 ((ctr+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                  outline='pink', fill='pink',
                  tags=('rect')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, for instance, create two rectangles of different colors to form a paddle, and move them simultaneously.
It would be fun if the "cigarette" would "burn", and get shorter as the game progresses.

That said, `tkinter` should be used with a `mainloop`, not within a `while` loop. the same it true for the use of `time.sleep` instead of `root.after()`

```
import tkinter as TK
import time

VERT, HOREZ = 0, 1
xTOP, yTOP = 0, 1
xBTM, yBTM = 2, 3
MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT = 640, 480
xSTART, ySTART = 50, 200
BALL_SIZE = 10
RUNNING = True

def close():
    global RUNNING
    RUNNING = False
    root.destroy()

def move_right(event):
    if canv.coords(paddle1)[xBTM]<(MAX_WIDTH-7):
        canv.move(paddle1, 20, 0)
        canv.move(paddle2, 20, 0)                   ## here

def move_left(event):
    if canv.coords(paddle1)[xTOP]>7:
        canv.move(paddle1, -20, 0)
        canv.move(paddle2, -20, 0)                  ## here

def determineDir(ball,obj):
    global delta_x,delta_y
    if (ball[xTOP] == obj[xBTM]) or (ball[xBTM] == obj[xTOP]):
        delta_x = -delta_x            
    elif (ball[yTOP] == obj[yBTM]) or (ball[yBTM] == obj[yTOP]):
        delta_y = -delta_y

root = TK.Tk()
root.title("Bouncing Ball")
root.geometry('%sx%s+%s+%s' %(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT, 100, 100))
root.bind('<Right>', move_right)
root.bind('<Left>', move_left)
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', close)

canv = TK.Canvas(root, highlightthickness=0)
canv.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

top = canv.create_line(0, 0, MAX_WIDTH, 0, fill='blue',
                     tags=('top'))
left = canv.create_line(0, 0, 0, MAX_HEIGHT, fill='blue',
                      tags=('left'))
right = canv.create_line(MAX_WIDTH, 0, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT,
                  fill='blue', tags=('right'))
bottom = canv.create_line(0, MAX_HEIGHT, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT,
                  fill='blue', tags=('bottom'))

ball = canv.create_rectangle(0, 0, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE,
                  outline='black', fill='black', tags=('ball'))

## here ##########################################################
paddle1 = canv.create_rectangle(100, MAX_HEIGHT - 20, 140, 470,
                  outline='black', fill='white', tags=('rect'))
paddle2 = canv.create_rectangle(140, MAX_HEIGHT - 20, 170, 470,
                  outline='black', fill='yellow', tags=('rect'))
## here ##########################################################

#row is 64 boxes wide
brick=list()

#trachea
for i in range(32,34):
    for row in range(0,5):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#first line of lungs and trachea
for i in range(26,31):
    for row in range(5,6):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(32,34):
    for row in range(5,6):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))
for i in range(35,40):
    for row in range(5,6):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#second line of lungs and trachea
for i in range(24,31):
    for row in range(6,7):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(32,34):
    for row in range(6,7):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))
for i in range(35,42):
    for row in range(6,7):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#third line of lungs and trachea
for i in range(23,31):
    for row in range(7,8):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(32,34):
    for row in range(7,8):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))
for i in range(35,43):
    for row in range(7,8):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#fourth line of lungs and trachea
for i in range(22,31):
    for row in range(8,9):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(32,34):
    for row in range(8,9):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))
for i in range(35,44):
    for row in range(8,9):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#fifth line of lungs and bifurcation of trachea
for i in range(21,45):
    for row in range(9,10):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#sixth line of lungs and bifurcation of trachea
for i in range(20,46):
    for row in range(10,11):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#seventh-ninth lines of lungs
for i in range(19,31):
    for row in range(11,14):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(35,47):
    for row in range(11,14):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#tenth-fourteenth lines of lungs
for i in range(18,31):
    for row in range(14,19):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(35,48):
    for row in range(14,19):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#fiftenth-eighteenth lines of lungs
for i in range(17,31):
    for row in range(19,23):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(36,49):
    for row in range(19,23):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#ninteenth line of lungs
for i in range(17,30):
    for row in range(23,24):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(37,49):
    for row in range(23,24):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#twentieth line of lungs
for i in range(17,29):
    for row in range(24,25):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(38,49):
    for row in range(24,25):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#twenty-first line of lungs
for i in range(17,28):
    for row in range(25,26):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(39,48):
    for row in range(25,26):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#twenty-second line of lungs
for i in range(17,27):
    for row in range(26,27):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(40,48):
    for row in range(26,27):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#twenty-third line of lungs
for i in range(18,26):
    for row in range(27,28):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(41,48):
    for row in range(27,28):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#twenty-fourth line of lungs
for i in range(19,25):
    for row in range(28,29):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(42,47):
    for row in range(28,29):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

#twenty-fifth line of lungs
for i in range(19,24):
    for row in range(29,30):
        brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

for i in range(43,47):
    for row in range(29,30):
      brick.append(canv.create_rectangle(i*10, row*10,
                     ((i+1)*10)-2, ((row+1)*10)-2,
                      outline='pink', fill='pink',
                      tags=('rect')))

delta_x = delta_y = 1
xold,yold = xSTART,ySTART
canv.move(ball, xold, yold)

while RUNNING:
    objects = canv.find_overlapping(canv.coords(ball)[0],
                                    canv.coords(ball)[1],
                                    canv.coords(ball)[2],
                                    canv.coords(ball)[3])

    #Only change the direction once (so will bounce off 1st
    # block even if 2 are hit)
    dir_changed=False
    for obj in objects:
        if (obj != ball):
            if dir_changed==False:
                determineDir(canv.coords(ball),canv.coords(obj))
                dir_changed=True
            if (obj >= brick[0]) and (obj <= brick[len(brick)-1]):
                canv.delete(obj)
            if (obj == bottom):
                text = canv.create_text(330,400,text="OOPS! TRY AGAIN!")
                canv.coords(ball, (xSTART,ySTART,
                             xSTART+BALL_SIZE,ySTART+BALL_SIZE))
                delta_x = delta_y = 1
                canv.update()
                time.sleep(3)
                canv.delete(text)
    new_x, new_y = delta_x, delta_y
    canv.move(ball, new_x, new_y)

    canv.update()
    time.sleep(0.005)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had made two rectangles with different colors, but had made paddle = paddle_1 + paddle_2 (if that makes sense?), and what happened was that I had a cigaret, but it didn't move. The top right pink brick of the lung did though!!!